# org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: unknown error: session deleted because of page crash

Tags: selenium

I am getting thw following error while running the code headless on a server.

I have also incorporated the following two ways:

1. `chromeOptions.addArguments("--disable-dev-shm-usage");`
2. `chromeOptions.addArguments("--no-sandbox");`

Still no success.

Error:

```
org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: unknown error: session deleted because of page crash
from unknown error: cannot determine loading status
from tab crashed
  (Session info: headless chrome=83.0.4103.116)
Build info: version: '3.14.0', revision: 'aacccce0', time: '2018-08-02T20:19:58.91Z'
System info: host: 's2c-beta-app', ip: '127.0.0.1', os.name: 'Linux', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '4.4.0-1121-aws', java.version: '1.8.0_275'
Driver info: org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver
```

How can I resolve this error?

Comment: I can't remember why, but when you use the `--no-sandbox` arg it sometimes causes problems when it is not listed first. Try making sure `chromeOptions.addArguments("--no-sandbox");` is the first argument added if you haven't already.

Comment: Another possibility is you are running out of disk space. How are you running the tests?

Comment: I have placed the chromeOptions.addArguments("--no-sandbox"); as the first option only. I am running it on the server. Installed the chrome on it.